# How to get my Desktop Icons back in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop, icons

Yesterday I restart my laptop and all my desktop icons dissapear, however the Desktop folder is ok. I have done all the tricks I have found and nothing seems to work.

I have tried this
-Rclick on desktop -> personalize -> Desktop icons -> default
-Check the registry for a missing explorer.exe value
-Uninstall Stardock Fences

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you last install or change on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps - [(From Microsoft Support)](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-us/help/a7453aef-50cf-45f5-b26d-3b32a9e8e4d61033.mspx)

### To show desktop icons

Right-click the desktop, point to View, and then click Show Desktop Icons.

A check mark will appear, indicating that desktop icons are displayed on your desktop.

(I am guessing that fences disables the normal desktop icons, if the above doesn't help, please say and I will change answer to a more general Windows fix)