# Restoring missing desktop icons in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get my Desktop Icons back in Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/50402/how-to-get-my-desktop-icons-back-in-vista)

My Windows Vista Desktop icon are all gone and I cant set them again! Is there any registry key to show them back? I used `regsvr32 /u shell32.dll` command but still nothing shows? what should I do?

Comment: Which desktop icon(s) ? All application icons are the system ones such as Recycle bin et al? Look at @ http://superuser.com/questions/50402/how-to-get-my-desktop-icons-back-in-vista

Comment: yes, all desktop icon, My Computer, recycle bin,... and it doesn't set again through windows adjust desktop icon

Answer (score 0):

I believe all of them except "Recycle Bin" can be placed on the desktop by right-clicking the item in the Start Menu and choosing "Show on Desktop."